# Recursion breaks type checking on overloaded functions

Tags: typescript

Given the following very similar functions:

```
function transform1 <T extends string>(value: T): T;
function transform1 <T extends string>(value: T[]): T[]; // error, can't return 0
function transform1 <T extends string>(value: T | T[]) {
  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return value[0];
  }
}

function transform2 <T extends string>(value: T): T;
function transform2 <T extends string>(value: T[]): T[];
function transform2 <T extends string>(value: T | T[]) {
  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    return 0; // ok somehow?
  } else {
    return transform2([value])[0];
  }
}
```

Why is it that for the second one, I am not warned about returning `0`? The only difference is that in the second one I am calling `transform2` again (recursion). Ignore the fact that this call will break at runtime since `0` will be returned and `0[0]` is `undefined`.

Why does recursion stop TypeScript from checking it? I'm forced to explicitly annotate the function return type here:

```
function transform2 <T extends string>(value: T | T[]): T | T[] {
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mppv7m)

Comment: I think this is only tangentially about recursion; the real issue has to do with the inferred return type for the implementation and whether it is "related" to the return types for the set of call signatures.  [This](https://tsplay.dev/WKO7zW) is what it looks like when you explicitly define the impl return type.  For `transform1` the compiler infers `string | 0` which it does not see as related to `T | T[]`, but for `transform2` it infers `T | 0` which it *does* see as related to `T | T[]`.  The exact rules are weird, though and I don't know how well documented they are.

Comment: As for the warning about recursion, that only happens if the type definitions are circular; if you've annotated the return types of the call signatures, then there's no circularity.  Anyway, this feels like two separate things, so I'm not sure they both belong in one question.

Comment: Do you want any of this written up as an answer?  Or am I still missing something about the situation?

Comment: Oh, right, as [Ryan has said to me before](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44661#issuecomment-865142074): "The rules are a mess of backcompat that no one wanted to write down."  It says "assignable to or from" but that's not quite what's going on here.  I doubt I'll find the true answer without stepping through the compiler impl and I'm probably not going to do that.

Comment: Yeah ok, I just used recursion because that's when I encountered the problem. I'll accept your explanation as an answer as it does answer my question.

Comment: All right, I'll write up an answer when I get a chance (leaving off the part about "shouldn't it warn me about recursion?" since that' really a separate post , so I hope you'll [edit] it out of this one)

Comment: As a practical answer, I suggest always explicitly declaring the return type on the implementation, not just the overload signatures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type checking for [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) function statements is a bit weird and not well documented.  The set of call signatures is compared to the implementation signature, and if the compiler decides that they aren't sufficiently "related" to each other, then it will issue an error (albeit not a very *helpful* error, see [ms/TS#48186](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48186)).

In your example code, the compiler has to infer the implementation return type from the implementation body.  For `transform1` it infers `string | 0` (which you can verify by copying the implementation to a new function and seeing the inferred return type), since `value[0]` is getting a character of a string, I think.  For `transform2` it infers `T | 0` (again, verifiable by copying), since `value` is narrowed to `T`, and `transform2([value])` returns `T[]`, and indexing into it is `T`.

That means, from the type checker's standpoint, these are your functions:

```
function transform1<T extends string>(value: T): T;
function transform1<T extends string>(value: T[]): T[] // error!
function transform1<T extends string>(value: T | T[]): string | 0 {
  throw new Error()
}

function transform2<T extends string>(value: T): T;
function transform2<T extends string>(value: T[]): T[];
function transform2<T extends string>(value: T | T[]): T | 0 {
  throw new Error()
}
```

(And so recursion is a bit of a red herring here.)

The first one errors because `string | 0` is not seen as properly "related" to `T | T[]`, while the second one is acceptable because `T | 0` *is* seen as properly "related" to `T | T[]`.  I don't really know *why*; for the first one it seems obvious that `T[]` cannot possibly be a `string` or `0` since `T extends string`.  For the second one it seems equally impossible that `T[]` cannot possibly be a `string` or `0` for the same reason.  All that means is that the compiler isn't really using such logic to allow/disallow call signatures.  I *guess* that the presence of the generic causes the compiler to be more lenient and not bother checking if `T` and `T[]` are compatible or not.

In looking for an authoritative answer I rediscovered a somewhat related issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#44661](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44661), where, when asked about the rules for comparing overload call signatures with implementations, @RyanCavanaugh [said](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44661#issuecomment-865142074):

> The rules are a mess of backcompat that no one wanted to write down.
>
> Basically the idea is to detect totally wrong situations and not too much else extra, keeping in mind the limitation that we're analyzing the function body opaquely.

So that's the closest I can get to an answer: `string | 0` is "totally wrong" for `T[]`, whereas `T | 0` is, apparently, *not* "totally wrong", at least to the extent the compiler's cursory check for "wrongness" can detect.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAdghgtgpgzgBwgYxgAgPICcCWBzNAb1DTQDMBXMZAFxwHsw0asIw4z6soBGAHgAqaGAA8aMMABM4aOCxxg8APgAUANwgAbCjABcaAQEp9AgNwlyVWgyYs2HLr0HCxE6bPmLVG7XoMBtAF1jAMDTNAB6COEsLC4AGjRkNgByGjQsGBoKLCYABgtKajpGZlZ2Tm5+IVFxKRk5XC91LR0TNAAfUMMiC1IcMjQVAEFYiABPADocOFHWcZbfQx7iEFJ1jKyc-PM19YBfYU04dFWN0kzs3LQfHX88sL60fYsXveRGOHpNGEnNejwKjsFUcPBUACIABYwTT-cHLSLRKHg0CovZFaylYEOKoYABGJywahgkmctTcDU8ykWbQMnW6vT2-UGIzGUxmcwmNJgCLO50u2zQeV2G0OMJOjPOmyuTFuMHujyZz1eFiiGJKtnKON4+MJxNJNVc9Q8TWpcvaXQEQRCjQUBC6BRAhSsGrK9kqUAATGSje5bc1zQYQmZncUbG6QdxvYa6n6qd5Wn4rcETEERZYw1itR7oy5Y5TTQnfBaGXzmUNOezZmzubynhcttdhYi0PQANayeiwSH0ADuAH4nmLjqd69LBdicyp-HLggr06Q3ou0aR1eHJ45PbqYESST78ya7UXaUJLdbJesBhW2dNq-NaysxwKm+Eoq2O19u33B0rhxKy+sz6au6m7TrOhjzkOKp7G+a5ZiBUbbruBp5hSh4BomJbJiEeT0gIaJom8oCQLAiAoOgAAyOBtqOTroi667ZqC+5of6ZqYUGJjpnBwGRk4MasfG3KpimoShpivHatUqHGmxx5Jnh1r6Gx9K4QBNCQnEvZoGAMDaQAorEXAqIY0Hia6G5RixslCYGRhceZjEIV61lxoWwndCJ3EMfBfG5uSNnuXZimiaeQoXqQGlaTpeloIZcRYCZZl0aAREgEAA)